# Check for same character value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to verify when a column has all the same values for the same group. Here is a sample of my table data:

[image: Sample Data]

So using this data, for example. I want to check to see if all values of `Status` is the same for every row with the same `TPID`. So `TPID` 60210 should result with True since both items have a `Status` of A. However, `TPID` 60061 should result in false since two of the `Line_Item` show A and the rest P.

I intend to update a different table using this information, setting its `status` using a CASE statement. But I'm at a loss how to check against this column to find the values I desire.

Comment: Why not use `GROUP BY TPID, Status` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE_Count
AS
(
   SELECT TPID, COUNT(DISTINCT Status) CNT
   FROM TableName
   GROUP BY TPID
 )

 UPDATE AnotherTableName
 SET ColumnName = (
   CASE WHEN CTE_Count.CNT = 1 -- all row has same status
      THEN SomeValue
    ELSE SomeOtherValue END
)
FROM AnotherTableName
INNER JOIN CTE_Count ON ...
```